# Understanding the inverse of a transposed matrix

Tags: matrices

$$(5A^T)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 & -1 \\
5 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$(A^T)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3/5 & -1/5 \\
1 & 2/5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3/5 & 1 \\
-1/5 & 2/5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-2/5 & 1 \\
-1/5 & 3/5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this how it is done? I'm not sure if $det$ is ever used when going from an inverted matrix to a normal matrix. I thought $AA^{-1}$ always resulted in an identity matrix, but it doesn't seem so here. At which step did I go wrong?

$$AA^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1/25 & 0 \\
0 & 1/25 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: How did you go from your $A^{-1}$ to $A$ in steps 3 and 4? Also, did you forget to divide a term by $5$ in step 2?

Comment: $A_{11}$ became $-A_{22}$ and $A_{22}$ became $-A_{11}$.

Comment: I'm not sure where this division comes from. I divided both sides between steps 1 and 2. $-3$ became $-3/5$, $-1$ became $-1/5$, etc.

Comment: Sorry that comment was incorrect on the missing 5 term, but http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%7B%7B-3%2F5%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B-1%2F5%2C+2%2F5%7D%7D

Comment: Did the above resolve your issues? Regards

Comment: Somewhat. I can see now what to do, I'm just not sure why it is done. Thanks for your help, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$(\lambda A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}A^{-1}$$
so your second equality is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

actually you have to multiply by $5$ not divise by $5$ $(5A^T)^{-1} = \frac{1}{5}{(A^T)}^{-1} $

Comment: This seems counterintuitive. I thought "whatever you do on the left side you do on the right side", re: basic fundamentals of algebra. Why is it divided?

Comment: I just tried using multiplication instead and no dice. I get a matrix of {25, 0 \\ 0, 25} for $AA^{-1}$.